# Getting Key From Maximum Value Of A Tuple At A Certain Index In A Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, max, min

For example, I have the following dictionary:
{"A": (4, 5), "B": (123, 2), "C": (35, 0), "D": (53, 111)}.
I want to get the key which has the highest value and the lowest value in the dictionary in the 2nd index of the value. For example, the key associated with the highest value in the 2nd index would be "D" and the lowest value in the 2nd index would be "C".

Comment: Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: `heapq.nlargest(1, d.items(), lambda x: x[1][1])` returns the largest (key, value) tuple. use `nsmallest()` to get the smallest. `max()` also works.